# Why is there no predicate in "we the people"?

Tags: grammar, predicate

I can't get the idea why. Haven't found anything on the internet

Comment: can you give some context? is this referring to the [Preamble to the US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preamble_to_the_United_States_Constitution)?

Comment: Assuming you **are** talking about the preamble, the actual sentence (if you exclude all of the flowery phrasing) is "We the people ordain and establish this Constitution." Looks like "Constitution" is the predicate to me...

Comment: @Catija the predicate(s) would be *ordain* and *establish*

Comment: @costrom Sure. It still includes the object, though (if there is one)... so technically we're both half right.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there is no predicate is "we" and "the people" are two elements **apposed**. The linked [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) defines **apposition** as:

> a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun
>   phrases, are placed side by side, with one element serving to identify
>   the other in a different way. The two elements are said to be in
>   apposition. One of the elements is called the appositive, although its
>   identification requires consideration of how the elements are used in
>   a sentence.

You can visit the link and read it to understand further how it works.